# 2-dimensional random walk

Tags: plotting, random

```
b = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
ListlinePlot[b, PlotRange -> 35]
```

I am so new to Mathematica. I am trying to generate a 2-dimensional walk with variance =1 and plot this.
However, I do not get its plot.

Can you help me?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FoldList[Plus, {0, 0}, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}]] // Line // Graphics
```

Answer (score 7):

Generate a list of random numbers and [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html):

```
b = Accumulate @ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];

ListLinePlot[b, PlotRange -> 35]
```

[image]

For 2D, you can generate pairs of random numbers and `Accumulate`:

```
SeedRandom[1]

b2 = Accumulate @ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}];

ListLinePlot[b2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need {500,2}? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bora, `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, m}]` generates an nXm matrix the entries of which are independent realizations of a random variable distributed `NormalDistribution[0, 1]`.

Comment: One last question. Is there any way to start the random walk at the origin? I am really grateful for your help.

Comment: Prepend the list with `{0,0}` before accumulating: `b2 = Accumulate @ Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}], {0,0}]`

Comment: Assuming that the x and y axes are equivalent, it's probably worth using the `AspectRatio -> Automatic` option on `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSeifert; good point. Updated with your suggestion.